# Como atualizar o JTextArea em cada iteração do loop com SwingWorker?

Tags: java, swing, loop, swingworker

Tenho uma classe que herda do `SwingWorker` e estou pegando informações de um arquivo `.txt` e jogando para o `JTextArea`, e gostaria de ir executando atualização do `JTextArea` enquanto o loop está executando, só que não está funcionando da maneira que quero, pois está executando todo o loop e somente apos todo o processamento do arquivo `.txt` que no caso tem mais de 100 mil linhas é que atualiza o `JTextArea`, com isso o Swing acaba travado e não mostrando nada para o usuário.

Repito, já herdei o `SwingWorker` para lidar com isso, mas não resolve o meu problema.

Tirando os comentários das linhas do `JOptionPane` no método `protected void process(List<String> pairs)`, faz com que o aplicativo execute da maneira que quero, ou seja, percorre o loop e da um `append()` no `JTextArea`, fiz isso apenas para demonstração.

Já tem quatro dias que estou pesquisando uma solução e nada. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Espero ter sido claro.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


/**
 *
 * @author claytonpereira
 */
public class Arquivo_txt_task  extends javax.swing.SwingWorker<Void,String>{

    static Vector conteudo;
    String data;
    volatile static FileOutputStream out = null;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    String arquivo_csv;
    String arquivo_csv_ajustado;
    static JTextArea mensagem;
    JFileChooser selecionaarquivo = TelaImportacaoSisobMensal.selecionaarquivo;
    JTextArea converte_txt_to_csv = TelaImportacaoSisobMensal.Converte_txt_to_csv;
    File arquivo = TelaImportacaoSisobMensal.arquivo;

        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
           List<String> texto = format_txt_to_csv(arquivo);
           int i = 0;
           while(i<texto.size()){
           publish(texto.get(i));


           i++;

           }         

        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> pairs) {

     for (String texto : pairs) {

            // TelaImportacaoSisobMensal.Converte_txt_to_csv.revalidate();
            TelaImportacaoSisobMensal.Converte_txt_to_csv.setVisible(true);
            TelaImportacaoSisobMensal.Converte_txt_to_csv.append(texto + "\n");
            //JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
           // pane.showMessageDialog(null, "Atualizando Registros ..........!");
            System.out.print("\n" +" rodando dentro de process ........ " + texto +  "=="  + "\n");

        }




    }

    public Vector format_txt_to_csv(File arquivo) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, StringIndexOutOfBoundsException {
         Vector texto = new Vector(8, 3); 

try (
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(arquivo)) {
            BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = leitor.readLine()) != null) {

                String livro_n = strLine.substring(0, 6);
                String folha_n = strLine.substring(6, 11);
                String termo_obito_n = strLine.substring(11, 21);
                String data_lavr_certidao_obito = strLine.substring(21, 29);
                String benef_inss_n = strLine.substring(29, 39);
                String nome_falecido = strLine.substring(39, 115);
                // String nome_falecido_ajustado = nome_falecido.trim();
                String nome_mae_falecido = strLine.substring(115, 147);
                // String nome_mae_falecido_ajustado = nome_mae_falecido.trim();

                String data_Nascimento = strLine.substring(147, 155);
                String data_Obito = strLine.substring(155, 163);
                String cpf = strLine.substring(163, 174);
                String nit = strLine.substring(174, 185);
                String tipo_identifica_cartorio = strLine.substring(185, 186);
                String Id_cartorio = strLine.substring(186, 200);

                String line = "";
                line = line + livro_n + ";" + folha_n + ";" + termo_obito_n + ";"
                        + data_lavr_certidao_obito + ";" + benef_inss_n + ";"
                        + nome_falecido + ";" + nome_mae_falecido + ";"
                        + data_Nascimento + ";"
                        + data_Obito + ";"
                        + cpf + ";" + nit + ";"
                        + tipo_identifica_cartorio + ";"
                        + Id_cartorio + ";";

                        texto.add(line);

            }

            return texto;
        }

    }
```

Comment: O problema é q voce nao está usando a classe como ela deveria ser usada. Toda a programacao incremental de texto deveria ser feita paralelamente a Thread principal, ou seja, dentro do doinbackground, e para que vc consiga atualizar corretamente a cada iteração, passar os textos de cada uma das iterações para o publish e concatenar no campo de texto via process. Quanto a ocorrer rapido, mesmo q vc faça conforme eu disse, isso sempre irá ocorrer pq o java executa conforme a velocidade do processamento do seu laço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de tentativas e erros consegui resolver chamando um Thread.sleep(); não sei se é a opção correta a se utilizar, mas para mim funcionou .